# Private Server On Google Cloud Platform and CloudFlare

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, cpanel, cloudflare, nameservers

I am little new to hosting and so I am confused for take step. My current situation is like below

I have one big wordpress site in site ground. Domain is from Godaddy and I am using CloudFlar. I want move this site on Google cloud Instance. So I have created Google cloud instance and have installed Cpanel/WHM. I have copied site on newly created cpanel account. Now My confusion is How I should change DNS for point my domain to Google cloud.

> Domain on : Godaddy, Using CloudFlare : Yes, Current Hosting : Site
>   Ground, New Destination Hosting : Google Cloud, My Current Domain :
>   example.com

For More information I have setup host like `host.example.com` and NameServer as `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` on Google cloud. Let me know someone can help me for required step to change DNS so I can successfully move without downtime.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the IP address for your domain in the DNS records which are hosted either with godaddy or with cloudflare. If you are not sure, do a `dig NS yourdomain.com` See which dns server's are coming. and accordingly make the change.